# How to do this in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I need to do the following:

`(defn make-menu []
  (for [i (range 3)]
    '(+ i 100)))`

I need make-menu to return: ('(+ 0 100) '(+ 1 100) '(+ 2 100))

Please note that the vector contains non-evaluated functions.

Is it possible to do this in Clojure?

Thank you for all your help!

Jakub

Answer (score 5):

```
(defn make-menu [] (for [i (range 3)] (list '+ i 100)))
```

or

```
(defn make-menu [] (for [i (range 3)] `(+ ~i 100)))
```

The first form is just a list of three elements: the symbol + quoted, i which evaluates to the value bound in the for list comprehension and 100.

The second form is an example of syntax-quote.
Note the difference between normal quote `'` and syntax-quote: the second allows evaluation of subforms, by prefixing `~`. Also it fully qualifies symbols, so `+` becomes `clojure.core/+`. Normal quote simply quotes every subelement in the quoted form, so no evaluation is possible there.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was a pretty quick response! I really appreciate it!